# How to get full index information using NodeJS MongoDB to be able to recreate the same index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing

Docs say, use Collection.indexInformation({full: true}) to return full information about the indexes on collection. However, this only gives partial info.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#indexInformation

I need full info so that I can "copy" (recreate) the same index on a different collection.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by partial info ? It does give you all the info about all the indexes

Comment: Well, I only get the following information:

{
key: Object
name: "_id_"
ns: "uns.Amenities"
v: 2
} but I'd like to get info about the options the index was created with (unique? name? collation?) so that I can recreate the same index in a different collection.

Comment: not sure why but I've tested it's working getting all details related to all indexes

Comment: Yes, it does give details to ALL indexes, but not ALL details about those indexes. In other words, I cannot reproduce the same index on a different server based on the information this returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response does not separate the `options` and `keys` of index, rather it merges them into one object. To be able to recreate the same index, you need to parse it.

```
export function parseIndexInformation(index) {
  const keys = index.key;
  const options = {};

  delete index.v;
  delete index.ns;
  delete index.key;

  for (let option in index) {
      options[option] = index[option];
  }

  return {keys, options};
}
```